# Android ListView delete invisible row

Tags: android, listview

In my app, I need to delete some rows form the `ListView`. I can remove from the data source and notify adapter that data has changed. But if I'm deleting rows above the *current visible ones*, the list view scrolls down, which I don't like. I wish to make the process as smooth as possible. What can I do?

Comment: You can always use scrollTo method if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this when you delete some row

```
// save index and top position
int index = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = myList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// notify dataset changed or re-assign adapter here

// restore the position of listview
myList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```